# How to play against computer in android app - tic tac toe

Tags: java, android

I have a tic tac game setup and require some help on code implementation on having it work for computer vs human, probably with the minmax algorithm. I have it currently set up for player vs player but how can I include code for player vs computer to work as I'm at a lost with this.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
        return;
    }

    if (playerOneMove) {
        ((Button) v).setText("X");
        ((Button) v).setTextColor(playerX);
    } else {
        ((Button) v).setText("O");
        ((Button) v).setTextColor(playerO);
    }

    turnsCount++;

    if (checkGameIsWon()) {
        if (playerOneMove) {
            player1Wins();
        } else {
            player2Wins();
        }
    } else if (turnsCount == 9) {
        draw();
    } else {
        playerOneMove = !playerOneMove;
        switchPlayerTurn();
    }
}

private boolean checkGameIsWon() {
    String[][] field = new String[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
            && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
            && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
        return true;
    }

    if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
            && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
            && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your onClick method it'll either be:

(1) the opponent's move (this is where you swap the X's and O's)

(2) a victory for the last player to move

(3) a draw (all boxes are already filled and nobody can move)

---

So you just write some code to handle (1) - as in make a decision for the AI.

What I'd suggest is making a method which checks for winning state *independently of the board state*.  So you need to pass it a matrix or 3x3 array.

You run it to see if the moving player won.

Then for each empty spot, you make a copy of the current board state and for that copy only, fill in one of the blanks with the moving player's colour/shape/icon/character.  Then pass each of those arrays to the checking algorithm.

That tells you (the AI) if you have a win on your move.  (If more than one move wins, just pick one at random)

If none of your moves win immediately, then you again make a copy of the current board state for each empty spot - but now for the enemy (i.e. the human).  Then fill in one of those spots for each copy, and pass that to your 'does this win' algorithm.  That tells you if the human has an immediate win on their turn (e.g. if you did nothing and they got another turn, or if you played somewhere useless).

If they have a win ... spoil it!  Muahahaha!  Take that fleshbags!  :D

If there are no wins or loses, you can play randomly.

With 386 era computers this would have been blindingly fast, so even though it's a lot of comparisons it's still super fast on modern hardware (even a watch/phone).

---

Even so it may be worth thinking about speeding it up.

E.g. having an internal representation based on numbers, not strings.

Let's say X = 1 and O = -1 and [empty] = 0

So now we *add* [0][0] + [0][1] + [0][2] if the total is 3 (or -3) then we have a win.

Of course that's using the mirror nature of the number line (above and below 0), so it doesn't generalise to more than 2 players.  (Whereas strings or characters would generalise to more than 2 players, but you'd need a bigger board and so on and so forth, and tic tac toe might not be interesting with that many players anyway (too many spoiling moves between each of your moves???))

Comment: are you ok to show this in sample code using the above snippet as  my issue is more the implementation side of things? thanks for your answer?